# generate an array with values of another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array with some values thats supposed to show some images randomized. what I want to do is create another array with the randomized images' name

```
var one = new Array("0.jpg", "1.jpg");//first array of images
 for(i=0; i<=6;i++)
  {
  var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*(length));//randomize the images of array one
 document.write('<img src="'+one[random])//display images
```

// after array one is randomized I want to create another array with the randomized images which would be array 2..How can I do this????
I was going to have `var shuffled=new Array(one[random]);` to create the second array but that doesnt work..any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `randomize` method to the `Array.prototype`:

```
Array.prototype.random = function () {
    var result = [],
        that = this.slice();
    this.forEach(function () {
        result.push(that.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * that.length), 1)[0]);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Then you can get your shuffled array with:

`var shuffled = one.random();`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/yApg2/4/)

Comment: You can also try `shuffled.push(one[random]);`, but the `randomize` method is a more generalized solution

Answer (score 0):

I used the top sample as reference and formatted becuase it was creating duplicates

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 var images = new Array('0.jpg', '1.jpg' , '2.jpg', '3.jpg'), result=[] ;
Array.prototype.random = function () {
    var that = this.slice();
    var length=images.length;
    this.forEach(function () {

   var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*(length));         
    result.push(images[rand]);  
   });
return result;
```

}

Summary: I have an array of images which i randomize to display on page, then I create another array with the randomized images that are shown